# Why can't None be cloned for a generic Option<T> when T doesn't implement Clone?

Tags: generics, rust, clone

Given a struct with a generic `Option<T>` where `T` might not implement `Clone` why can't `None` be cloned? Isn't a `None` of type `T` the same as any other `None`? For example:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: Vec<Option<T>>,
}

impl <T> Foo<T> {
    fn blank(size: usize) -> Foo<T> {
        Foo {
            bar: vec![None; size],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *" Isn't a `None` of type `T` the same as any other `None`?"* - no, `None` is a variant of `Option<T>`. Its full name would be `Option::<T>::None`, but you often don't need that since the type is usually *inferred*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't a `None` of type `T` the same as any other `None`?

Definitely not! Unlike reference-based languages where null is typically internally represented as a null pointer (pointer whose address is 0), Rust's `Option<T>` introduces no indirection and stores `T` inline when the option is `Some`. Since all enum variants have the type of the enum and therefore the same size, the `None` variant must still occupy at least as much space as `T`.

Having said that, it is technically true that the `None` value could be cloned without `T` being `Clone` simply because the `None` variant of the enum *doesn't* contain the `T`, it only stores the discriminator and reserves space that *could* contain `T` if the variant were to change to `Some`. But since Rust enum variants are not separate types, a trait bound defined for the enum must cover all variants.

See other answers more detailed explanations and instructions how to create a vector of `None` values of a non-cloneable `Option`.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers correctly point ouf, this is due to the way the `vec!`-macro is implemented. You can manually create a `Vec` of any `Option<T>` without requiring `T` to be `Clone`:

```
let bar = std::iter::repeat_with(|| Option::<T>::None).take(size).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

This will create `size`-number of `Option::<T>::None` and place them in a `Vec`, which will be pre-allocated to the appropriate size. This works for any `T`.

Comment: Added note: You can just use `repeat_with(|| None)`, it being an `Option<T>` is inferred. Just for clarity here.

Answer (score 3):

If one part can't be cloned, then no parts can be cloned. Think about this from a type perspective: you have a variable called `foo` of type `Option<T>`, where `T` isn't clonable. Sure, `None` can be cloned, but `Some(_)` can't, and the type of the variable doesn't tell you which it is. So, from a compile-time perspective, you can't clone the option.

Answer (score 2):

An `Option` can only be cloned if the inner `T` implements `Clone`:

```rust
impl<T> Clone for Option<T>
where
    T: Clone,
```

> Isn't a `None` of type `T` the same as any other `None`?

Actually, no. The Rust compiler does not even view `None` as a type. Instead, `None` is just a variant (subtype) of `Option<T>`. Try comparing `None`s of two different `T`s:

```rust
let a: Option<String> = None;
let b: Option<u8> = None;

assert_eq!(a, b)
```

You will see that they are in fact completely unrelated types:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     assert_eq!(a, b)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `String`, found `u8`
  |
  = note: expected enum `Option<String>`
             found enum `Option<u8>`
```

So the Rust compiler actually sees `None` as `Option::<T>::None`. This means that if `T` is not `Clone`, then `Option<T>` is not `Clone`, and therefore `Option::<T>::None` cannot be `Clone`.

To make your code compile, you must constrain `T` to `Clone`:

```rust
struct Foo<T: Clone> {
    bar: Vec<Option<T>>,
}

impl <T: Clone> Foo<T> {
    fn blank(size: usize) -> Foo<T> {
        Foo {
            bar: vec![None; size],
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler knows that `T` is `Clone`, and the implementation of `Clone` for `Option<T>` (and `Option::<T>::None`) is fulfilled.

Comment: Your linked RFC doesn't have any bearing to the question at hand: *Variant types may not have inherent impls, or implemented traits*.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed If I understand you correctly there is no type theory reason that a `None` cannot be cloned, but rather the static analyzer doesn't have that functionality yet. Correct?

Comment: @HiDefender Well, the type theory reason is that enum variants are in fact not types. Instead, they are variants (subtypes) of an enum and their behaviour is determined by the enum that they are contained in. The way that the Rust compiler views enum variants may or may not change in the future.

Comment: @HiDefender I updated my question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Shepmaster Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of items is not too large, so that it overflows the stack if placed on it, you can construct the `Vec` from an array. The advantage of arrays is that they can be constructed from `const` values, even if the type is not `Copy`:

```rust
const NONE: Option<NonClone> = None;
Vec::from([NONE; 10])
```